# Enum methods vs string methods

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

Is it more efficient to use enums instead of string arrays, performance-wise?

I decided to test a particular method IsDefined, versus checking for a match-up inside a string array. I created an object of Stopwatch to test the runtime for each one.
The code, below:

Defined an enum outside of class Main:

```
 enum Color : byte { red, blue, green }
```

Inside Main:

```
string[] colArr = new string[] { "red", "blue", "green" };
string input = "green";
Stopwatch s1 = new Stopwatch();
int loopIterations = 0;

s1.Restart();
while (loopIterations++ < 100000000)
    foreach (var blah in colArr)
        if (blah == input)
            break;
s1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Runtime for foreach loop: {0}", s1.Elapsed);

loopIterations = 0;
s1.Restart();
while (loopIterations++ < 100000000)
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Color), input))
        continue;
s1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Runtime for IsDefined method returned value: {0}", s1.Elapsed);
```

And my output looks like this:

```
Runtime for foreach loop: 00:00:01.4862817
Runtime for IsDefined method returned value: 00:00:09.3421654
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So I wanted to ask if - assuming the code I wrote isn't, like, stupid or something - those numbers are normal, and if they are, in what way is using enums preferable to using a string array, specifically for the kind of jobs both would?

Comment: Both have their own purpose. You use enums for developer-friendlier APIs, and you use strings for user input. What did your research show?

Comment: You are using an enum like a string, of course that is less efficient. Instead store it as `Color`, f.e.: `Color input = Color.green;`. Then you dont need to check if it exists.

Comment: The call of `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Color), input)` will probably falsify your calculation as it requires to parse the string and do some unboxing. You may use `Enum.GetValues` as equivalent for `foreach(var blah in colArr)` to get a more proper result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't clarify this before, but how this works is, a user is asked to type a color, and then the program checks if that color exists. I decided to skip the input part, and instead just place the string "green" inside input. So it's unavoidable for the input type to be string, I can't store it in color, without first checking if it even exists, hence the call for IsDefined.

Comment: Then you already *have* your answer, don´t you? If all you have is just a string you have to convert that string to a valid enum in any way which is slow (reflection).

Comment: @ChenLeikehmacher: two things: 1) Provide the user a dropdownlist or the [`ColorDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.aspx). Then you don't need to check if it exists. 2) You are asking the wrong question. The user gives you only one input and you are measuring 100000000 `Enum.IsDefined` calls. Performance is the least thing you should care about in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, rather than performance a big reason for using enums over strings is maintainability of the code. E.g., trying to 'find all references' to Color.red can be done with a few clicks in visual studio. Trying to find strings isn't so easy. Always typing the strings is also error-prone. Although both problems could be alleviated somewhat by using constants, it's easier to use enums.

An enum can be seen as a constant integer value, which has good performance and has benefits such as using flags (masks). Comparing an int will be faster than comparing a string, but that's not what happens here. Mostly you want to do something for a specific value and you could test `if(someString == "red")` versus `if(someColVal == Color.red)`, in which case the latter should be faster.

Checking if a value exists in an enum can be slower with the `Enum.IsDefined`, but that function has to look up the enum-values each time in this loop.
Meanwhile the first test has a pre-defined array. For the strict comparison in performance to your first test, you could do something like:

```
var colvalues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color)).Cast<Color>().ToArray();  // or hardcode: var colvalues = new[]{Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green};
var colinput = Color.red;
while (loopIterations++ < 100000000)
    foreach (var blah in colvalues)
        if (blah == colinput)
            break;
```

Although as stated, finding if a value exists in an `enum` is normally not its primary function (mostly it's used for checking for a specific value). However it's integer base allows for other methods to check if a value is in an expected range, such as mask-checking or  `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=`

*edit* Seeing the comments about user input: mostly the input would be controlled, e.g.: the user is shown a menu. In a console environment that menu could be build with the numbers of the enum.
For example, enum `enum Color : byte { red = 1, blue, green }`, menu
1. red
2. blue
3. green

The user input would be an integer. On the other hand if typing is required, `IsDefined` would prevent having to retype the values and is good for ease of use. For performance the names could be buffered with something like `var colvalues = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color)).ToArray();`

Comment: Name: TBH, I wouldn't say that using masks is a benefit. IMHO it is not easy to maintain and leads to more code confusion and errors than any supposed benefits. It probably made sense in the memory-constrained 1990's, but in today's world, we probably are better off just maintaining the "selected" enums into collections.

Comment: @code4life Personally I love flags-enums with masks. (For single values as a color they would be useless of course). Not because of memory constraints, but you can easily add or remove values. e.g. a border-enum property: `someClass.Border |= Border.Left` sets the left border regardless if it's already set. If you do that with a collection, you could get infinite entries unless you add extra code to check if the value already is inside the collection

Answer (score 1):

The normal use for enums is to represent logical states or a limited range of options: in your example, if e.g. a product ever only comes in three colours. Using a string to represent colours in such a case has two drawbacks: you may misspell the name of a colour somewhere in your code, and get hard to track bugs; and string comparison is inherently slower than comparing enums (which is basically comparing integers).

`IsDefined()` uses type reflection, and thus should be slower than straight string comparison. There are cases where you want to convert enums to and from strings: usually when doing input/output such as saving or restoring configurations. That's slower, but input/output is typically dominated by the slowness of storage media and networks, so it's seldom a big deal.

Comment: I understand that it's not a big deal, but the point is that for input operations using a string will yield better (if inconsequential) performance gains. As I wrote in the comments of my question, the user is asked to type the name of a color, and the program looks for a match. For those types of jobs, using a string array is preferable.

Comment: @Chen you can convert string into enum **once** and then use IsDefined. Thats what IsDefined does internally . It converts string into enum once and then starts comparing. When you put that in loop, the convertion is also included in loop. So your benchmark is wrong. Because you are measuring overhead of converting string into enum.

Comment: _For those types of jobs, using a string array is preferable_ No. There is tradeoff between code readability and performance. With string array you make your code less maintainable and readable for no reasonable performance boost. @Chen

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but noticed the compared code snippets for the loops are not doing the looping in a similar fashion.
As in the first loop, you let the loop break once it finds the string in the string array but in the second scenario you dont let the loop stop but rather continue if the Enum.IsDefined finds the value.

When you actually let the loop in enum scenario to break if it finds the value, the enum scenario runs much faster...